# Haskell: Using one class in instance of another

Tags: haskell

I have a code to the following scheme:

```
class First s where
  func1 :: s -> s
class Second a where
  func2 :: s -> a s

data D s = D {value :: s}
myFunc2 :: First s => s -> D s
myFunc2 = undefined
```

In common func2's argument could not be instance of First. I want to make D instance of Second in only that cases when it's value instance of First.
Then I want to get this instance:

```
instance Second D where
  func2 = myFunc2
```

But I get an error:

```
No instance for (First s)
  arising from a use of `myFunc2'
```

Okay, let instance be:

```
instance First s => Second D where
  func2 = myFunc2
```

But this gives error:

```
Ambiguous constraint `First s'
  At least one of the forall'd type variables mentioned by the constraint
  must be reachable from the type after the '=>'
In the instance declaration for `Second D'
```

So, is there a way to get instance of class with some conditions from other classes, but without all type variables after '=>'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it helps to think about what is meant qualitatively by

```
class Second a where
    func2 :: s -> a s
```

A `Second` instance promises that `func2` is defined for *any* type `s`. But that's not true of `myFunc2`, because `myFunc2` is only defined for those `s` for which there exists a `First` instance. This means that as you have defined `First` and `Second`, it is not possible to use `myFunc2` in a `Second` instance (unless there existed a catch-all `forall s . First s` instance, but I'm assuming not, or you wouldn't have bothered to make a typeclass).

So, you will have to change at least one thing. You could redefine `Second` as Grzegorz suggested. If you don't like that, you could redefine `Second` like

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Second a s where
  func2 :: s -> a s

instance First s => Second D s where
  func2 = myFunc2
```

Note that this is saying something different than what you wrote originally, because now a `Second` instance does not guarantee that `func2` is polymorphic. But I think this is closer to what you mean when you say "make D instance of Second in only that cases when it's value instance of First". Maybe it will be acceptable in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the best what can I do with.

Answer (score 6):

The exact solution will depend on what the code is trying to do, but the problem is that the type signature you give to `func2` does not mention the `First s` constraint, whereas your definition of `func2` for the `Second D` instance needs it. The following compiles:

```
class First s where
  func1 :: s -> s
class Second a where
  func2 :: First s => s -> a s

data D s = D {value :: s}
myFunc2 :: First s => s -> D s
myFunc2 = undefined

instance Second D where
  func2 = myFunc2
```

Comment: The problem is func2's arguments could not be instance of First in common. I want to make D instance of Second in only that cases when it's value instance of First. I corrected question.